# Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".Mr508"}

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to fetch the comments username and their comment from instagram. But i am getting only usernames in both username and user_comment.

My code below :

```
try:
    load_more_comment = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class,'dCJp8')]")
    print("Found {}".format(str(load_more_comment)))
    i = 0
    while load_more_comment.is_displayed() and i < 5:
        load_more_comment.click()
        time.sleep(1.5)
        load_more_comment = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class,'dCJp8')]")
        print("Found {}".format(str(load_more_comment)))
        i += 1
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    pass

user_names = []
user_comments = []
comment = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('gElp9 ')
for c in comment:
    container = c.find_element_by_class_name('Mr508')
    name = container.find_element_by_class_name('_6lAjh').text
    content = container.find_element_by_tag_name('span').text
    content = content.replace('\n', ' ').strip().rstrip()
    user_names.append(name)
    user_comments.append(content)

print(user_names)
print(user_comments)
```

[image]

Please find html Text below:

```
<div class="C4VMK">
    <h3 class="_6lAjh ">
        <div
            class="                     Igw0E     IwRSH      eGOV_         _4EzTm                                       ItkAi                                                                       ">
            <span class="Jv7Aj mArmR MqpiF  "><a class="sqdOP yWX7d     _8A5w5   ZIAjV " href="/_anubhavgarg/"
                    tabindex="0">_anubhavgarg</a></span></div>
    </h3><span class="">Dada for all of us and dadi for the legend.</span>
    <div
        class="                     Igw0E     IwRSH      eGOV_         _4EzTm   pjcA_                                                         aGBdT                                                  ">
        <div class="_7UhW9  PIoXz       MMzan   _0PwGv         uL8Hv         "><a class="gU-I7"
                href="/p/CRDqn-YMocE/c/17922998680684965/" tabindex="0"><time class="FH9sR Nzb55"
                    datetime="2021-07-08T07:10:38.000Z" title="Jul 8, 2021">20h</time></a><button class="FH9sR">365
                likes</button><button class="FH9sR">Reply</button></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: well those locators looks to be dynamic in nature. Can you share that HTML in text format here ?

Comment: Update - Load more comment button is working now ! now in user_comments it is printing usernames only. updating the question please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with the below **xpath** to grab `user comment` from Instagram.

```
//button[text()='Reply']/../../preceding-sibling::span
```

**Explanation** : If you see in user comments section, you'd see `Reply` button in every comment, so keeping that in xpath makes it more reliable.

**Sample code  :**

```
try:
    for comments in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Reply']/../../preceding-sibling::span"):
        print(comments.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
except:
    print("There an issue, please check the code again.")
    pass
```

Comment: working thanks . but same xpath not working for 1st comment of post by sachin Tendulkar.

Comment: I have tried full xpath for 1st comment i.e photo caption-> content =driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/div[1]/article/div[3]/div[""1]/ul/div/li/div/div/div[2]/span").get_attribute('innerHTML')

Comment: no ! this one -> **My beloved Dadi. Happy birthday.<br><br>Wishing you a healthy and happy year ahead**

Comment: this is not a comment, it's a caption. please check that

Comment: Yes caption sorry ! actually i mentioned in above comment 1st comment i.e photo caption.

Comment: you caption you need to have a different locator

Comment: i have used full xpath for that - is there any other metho d?

Comment: you need to use this xpath `(//a[text()='sachintendulkar'])[2]/ancestor::h2/following-sibling::span` separately. but I see this question was just for  username  and their comment

Comment: Thanks and apologies ! next time onwards i will create seperate questions

Comment: for other profile this will not work -> //a[text()='sachintendulkar' right ?

Comment: no it won't. you will have to give profile name respectively